# Infragistics UltraWinGrid Automation using C#

Tags: c#, ui-automation, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I am working on UI automation part for Infragistics UltraWinGrid.

Using "Inspect" tool, I am able to see that Grid rendered as Pane, but I am not able to convert it into UltraWinGrid.

Basically, I want to read the row and cell value from the UltaWinGrid using C#.Net 4.0

Comment: Does the UltraWinGrid control support the UIA Grid pattern? If it does, you can call GetItem() through that pattern to get the item at a particular row and column. The Inspect SDK tool will show you whether the control claims to support the Grid pattern or not. So point Inspect to the control, and see if the IsGridPatternAvailable property is true or false in the list of properties for the control.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
            AutomationElement mTable = mElement;
            AutomationElementCollection elementCollection = null;
            elementCollection =
            mTable.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition);
            int mCount = elementCollection.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i <= elementCollection.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                if (elementCollection[i].Current.Name.ToUpper().IndexOf("ROW") >= 0)
                {
                    AutomationElement mDest = Share.GetElementByNameFromChild(elementCollection[i], ColumnName);
                    var pattern = ((LegacyIAccessiblePattern)mDest.GetCurrentPattern(LegacyIAccessiblePattern.Pattern));
                    String state = pattern.Current.Value;
                    if (Share.CompareString(state, SearchString))
                    {
                        watch.Stop();
                        var elapsedMs = watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
                        FileAdapter.WriteLog("Search value in Table col " + ColumnName + " and search string:  " + SearchString + "," + true.ToString() + "," + elapsedMs);
                        Share.wait(Utility.delayTime());
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Copy to text pad and see

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response.

Please note following points.
1. The Automation element type of the grid is "Pane" (not table).
2. Using Inspect tool, I am able to get AutomationIDs for each row in the Grid.
3. I am not able to read the text of whole row as well.
4. Each row is also gets rendered as "Pane" element and having AutomationID.
5.In the above code, You have used "Share.", I am not sure where it comes from.
6. Also from where this "LegacyIAccessiblePattern" comes from.

Request you to provide more details on the same, so that I can try at my end.

Thanks for your time and help.